# Find numbers within a range in an arbitrary number of nested lists

Tags: python, nested-lists

I have an arbitrary number of nested lists (let's say two for simplicity) with the same length that look something like that:

**EDIT**
In this edit I change the example lists to two specific, that seem to cause trouble:

```
l1 = [[96, 110], [49, 95, 122], [173, 218], [30], [80, 159], [95, 119, 150, 168]]
l2 = [[25, 110], [63, 126],     [130, 222], [42], [3],       [94, 119, 150, 176]]
```

Now I want a function that checks, for every index, if there exist entries (and which and how many) in every list that lay within a given range and returns them. 
Let's say the range is 20. In this example I would like to return

```
[[[110, 96], [110, 110]], [[63, 49], [126, 122]], [222, 218], [42, 30], [], [[95,94],[119, 119], [150, 150], [176, 168]]]
```

I know that for **two** lists I can use `itertools` like this:

```
result = []
for i in range(len(l1): # the lists have the same length 
  result.append(
  [[a,b] for (a, b) in itertools.product(l1[i], l2[i]) 
                 if a-20 <= b <=a+20])
```

In that example I would need to check whether or not my entry in the nested list is an int or not and use another way to compare my entries, but that's rather secondary.
The big question is how to do it with more than two lists. I have thougth about a recursive solution, but could not work out something properly.

**EDIT** 
With more than two lists I mean I have more lists like `l1` or `l2` with the same length as the others.

The solutions given by @MishaMelnyk and @AlainT are already really helpfull, but the results depent on the the order of the list
Result for the given solutions with order l1, l2:

```
[[[110, 96], [110, 110]], [[63, 49], [126, 122]], [[222, 218]], [[42, 30]], [], [[119, 119], [150, 150], [176, 168]]]
```

or order l2, l1

```
[[[110, 110]], [], [], [[30, 42]], [], [[95, 94], [119, 119], [150, 150], [168, 150]]]
```

Happy for any suggestions

Comment: I find your explanation here very confusing! Your code here also doesn't give the output `[[],[78,84],[6,7],[99,100]]`.

Comment: I'm wondering what the nested lists mean exactly, will it always be two dimensions at most, or can it be more.

Comment: When you say *how to do it with more than two lists* - do you mean the inner lists as in level of nesting, or rather number of the list themselves as in `l1`, `l2` **and** and `l3`? It is not very clear

Comment: If I am correctly understanding what you're asking, should [20,22] also be part of the output since they are less than 20 apart?

Comment: Also, just a side note, the `a-20 <= b <=a+20` seems confusing IMO. Why not just `abs(a-b) <= 20`?

Comment: @iamvegan: I am sorry, I tried to explain it as good as I could. It is true, my code does not return what I supposed. As Misha Melnyk pointed out I forgot [20,22]. I edited it.

Comment: @MishaMelnyk: Every list is a person and every sublist corresponds to a video. The person was instructed to select a frame from every video, in which he/she thougth an important action started.

Comment: Will all of the variables inside the outer list be lists, or will some be just integers like in the examples?

Comment: @MishaMelnyk as in the example there can be integers. Since it is a subjective 'measurement', a person could choose only one frame or even none, so an empty list is also a possiblity.

Comment: @Pibe_chorro What I mean, would the integers in the example be stored in lists, as you mentioned, empty lists are possible, so would that at each index there is a definite list, and there are just a number of indices (with list being the same length) or would some of the indices be replaced by integers like in the example. I am thinking `l2 = [[30],[22,84], ... ]` instead of what is shown above, or will it be exactly like in the example?

Comment: @MishaMelnyk It will be exactly like in the example. Anyway, it is not a big deal to change that and my lists are not huge. So if you have a suggestion that demands every entry to be a list, I am happy to hear it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I made based on what you mentioned:

```
l1 = [[80,112,270],[20,78], 6,             [99,134,240,300]]
l2 = [30,          [22,84],[7,122,189,279],[67,100]]
l3 = [60, [25, 70], [2], [110]]

def makeZip(maxRange, *args):
    for l in args: #For each index in the lists, converts any integers to lists
        for i in range(len(l)):
            if type(l[i]) == int:
                l[i] = [l[i]]

    z = zip(*args)
    #Zip makes lists for each video with all of the entries
    #Basically Equivilant to transposing a matrix in Lin Alg
    matches = []
    for l in z: #For each video, generates matching pairs
        videoMatches = []
        for m in makeMatch(maxRange, l): #For all of the pairs, add to list
            videoMatches.append(m)
        matches.append(videoMatches) #Add the list to the main list

    return matches

def makeMatch(maxRange, l):
    if len(l) == 1: #If only one list (person) then return all of the values sequentially (generator)
        for i in l[0]:
            yield [i]
        return

    matches = []
    for n in makeMatch(maxRange, l[1:]): #for each of the generated match from a recursive call
        for i in l[0]: #For all of the values of the current person
            if all([abs(i - x) < maxRange for x in n]): #Check if value works for all of the values already in the match
                matches.append([i] + n) #Sucessful match

    for m in matches: #when done with all of the matches, return them sequentially (generator)
        yield m

for m in makeZip(20, l1, l2, l3):
    print(m)
```

You might want to rename the variables though. Hopefully, the output is what should be for three lists.

One problem that you might have with this solution is that I'm pretty sure O(numVideos^numPeople) in the worst case where everything matches. Might be wrong about the complexity though.

Comment: I must be honest I am not experienced enough to fully understand what you did there but it is BRILLIANT and helps a lot! The only thing is, that I want the result, the ```matches``` in your code, to be a list of the same length as l1,l2 and l3. If an index has no overlapping entries in all lists, it should return an empty list. If it has more than one it should return a nested list.

Comment: Added comments to the code, check them out if you want to understand what's happening. Again, this method is pretty inefficient but is gonna get you what you want.

Comment: it seems the order of the lists have an impact on the result

Comment: Sorry the order does not really have an impact. It seems just to be an error with my data (read in from .mat files). These seem to be identical to normal lists, but in some way are different and cause an overflow

Answer (score 1):

Once you have solved the problem for two lists, you can use it iteratively by starting with the first two, then merge list 1 and list 2 and perform the check between the merged lists and list 3,  then merge list 3 to that and process the merged list with list 4 , and so on.

The comparison logic between two list could be greatly accelerated by sorting sublists in list1 and using bisect_left to find the first element 'b' that is >= to a-20,  then progress sequentially in the sorted elements until you get beyond a+20.  You can do that for every item 'a' in the corresponding sublist of list 2. This will give you a time complexity of O(NlogM) instead of O(N*M) which will become even more important as you merge lists in a multi-list process.

Here is a concrete example of the multi-list process.

*Note that I did not include the bisect search optimization in the matchSubLists function (that would only be needed if your sublists are large enough)*

```
def matchSubLists(sA,sB,match):
    return [ (a,b) for b in sB for a in sA if match(a,b) ]

def match2Lists(A,B,match):
    return [ matchSubLists(sA,sB,match) for sA,sB in zip(A,B)]

def merge2Lists(A,B):
    return [ sA+sB for sA,sB in zip(A,B) ]

def matchMultiLists(*L,match):
    result = [[] for _ in L[0]]
    merged = L[0]
    for Ln in L[1:]:
        matches = match2Lists(merged,Ln,match)
        result  = merge2Lists(result,matches)
        merged  = merge2Lists(merged,Ln)
    return result
```

ouput:

```
l1 = [[80,112,270], [20,78],  [6],             [99,134,240,300]]
l2 = [[30],         [22,84],  [7,122,189,279], [67,100]]
l3 = [[60],         [25, 70], [2],             [110]]

result = matchMultiLists(l1,l2,l3, match=lambda a,b:abs(a-b)<=20)
print(result)

[
  [(80, 60)],
  [(20, 22), (78, 84), (20, 25), (22, 25), (78, 70), (84, 70)],
  [(6, 7), (6, 2), (7, 2)],
  [(99, 100), (99, 110), (100, 110)]
]
```

*I used one entry sublists instead of int values to work with a more consistent data structure and avoid unnecessary exceptions in the logic*

**[EDIT]**

If you want the output to be the same independently of the order of the lists in the call to matchMultiList, you can add a sort before returning the result:

```
def matchMultiLists(*L,match):
    result = [[] for _ in L[0]]
    merged = L[0]
    for Ln in L[1:]:
        matches = match2Lists(merged,Ln,match)
        result  = merge2Lists(result,matches)
        merged  = merge2Lists(merged,Ln)
    # consistently ordered result (2-level sort)
    result = [ sorted( map(tuple,map(sorted,sR)) ) for sR in result ]
    return result
```

*Since you can use matchMultiLists with two lists, you don't need to add the sort to the match2Lists() function. In fact the 3 one-line functions could be defined inside of the matchMultiLists() function to avoid exposing them.*

output:

```
l1=[[96, 110], [49, 95, 122], [173, 218], [30], [80, 159], [95, 119, 150, 168]]
l2=[[25, 110], [63, 126],     [130, 222], [42], [3],       [94, 119, 150, 176]]

range20 = lambda a,b:abs(a-b)<=20

print(matchMultiLists(l1,l2, match=range20))
[[(96, 110), (110, 110)], [(49, 63), (122, 126)], [(218, 222)], [(30, 42)], [], [(94, 95), (119, 119), (150, 150), (150, 168), (168, 176)]]

print(matchMultiLists(l2,l1, match=range20))
[[(96, 110), (110, 110)], [(49, 63), (122, 126)], [(218, 222)], [(30, 42)], [], [(94, 95), (119, 119), (150, 150), (150, 168), (168, 176)]]
```

Comment: I am not sure if I got your suggestion right or maybe my explanation of the problem was not explicit enought. How would you merge the lists in a way that you can check whether or not the third list has entries that are within the same range as the entries I selected from the first two lists?

Comment: This solution works fine with the lists given here, but with two lists I want to match the order of the list changes the result: ```l1=[[96, 110], [49, 95, 122], [173, 218], [30], [80, 159], [95, 119, 150, 168]] ``` and ``` l2=[[25, 110], [63, 126], [130, 222], [42], [3], [94, 119, 150, 176]]```I cannot figure out why it makes a difference

Comment: Not sure what you mean there.  Can you update your question with this example and provide the expected output (and what is wrong with the current result)

Comment: To answer your first comment, that would mean you are looking for an intersection of matching numbers.  In that case the `merged` variable inside the loop would need to be updated differently: `merged = [[v for ab in sR for v in ab] for sR in result]`, This will produce matching pairs that form "cliques" of values that are close to another value in every other sublist.

Answer (score 0):

You can expand your solution to first choose all possible couples of sublists (at the same index) using [`combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations), and then go through all couples of items using [`product`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.product). Something like:

```py
import itertools

result = []

for sub_lists in zip(l1, l2 ,l3):
    for couple_subs in itertools.combinations(sub_lists, 2):
        result.append(
                      [[a,b] for a, b in itertools.product(*couple_subs) 
                       if abs(a-b) <= 20])
```

To handle unknown level of nesting you can first flatten the sub-lists before passing them to product:

```py
def flatten(l):
    for el in l:
        if isinstance(el, list):
            yield from flatten(el)
        else:
            yield el
```

And now you can use that in the code above as:

```py
[[a,b] for a, b in itertools.product(flatten(couple_subs[0]), flatten(couple_subs[1]))
                       if abs(a-b) <= 20]
```

**Ex:**

```
import itertools

l1 = [[1, [4, 11], 2], [3,4]]
l2 = [[5,6], [7,8]]
l3 = [[9, 10], [11, 12]]

result = []

def flatten(l):
    for el in l:
        if isinstance(el, list):
            yield from flatten(el)
        else:
            yield el

for sub_lists in zip(l1, l2 ,l3):
    for couple_subs in itertools.combinations(sub_lists, 2):
        result.append(
                      [[a,b] for a, b in itertools.product(flatten(couple_subs[0]), flatten(couple_subs[1]))
                       if abs(a-b) <= 3])

print(result)
```

Gives:

```
[[[4, 5], [4, 6], [2, 5]], [[11, 9], [11, 10]], [[6, 9]], [[4, 7]], [], [[8, 11]]]
```